# Why LibreOffice doesn't show AltChunks in docx document?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx, libreoffice

I use `OpenXML` to create Word document, and use `AltChunks` to copy part of other document in this one. Here just a simple snippet:

```
 const string _altChunkID = "AltChunkID1111";
 var chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, _altChunkID);

  string html =
         @"<html>
            <head/>
              <body>
               <h1>Html Heading</h1>
               <p>This is an html document in a string literal.</p>
              </body>
            </html>";


  using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))
    stringStream.Write(html);


  chunk.FeedData(ms);
  var altChunk = new AltChunk {Id = _altChunkID};
  mainPart.Document
         .Body
         .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
```

And it works. I open `Word` and see this `AltChunk`. But `LibreOffice` doesn's show me this `AltChunk`. In case when i open document in `Word` and save if `LibreOffice` starts to show `AltChunk`.
So what i doing wrong? Why is `Microsoft Word` showing document properly and `LibreOffice` isn't?

Comment: Can I make a guess? This behavior may be due to the fact that the download page [**Microsoft | Download Center**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) says "Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office" (not for LibreOffice)?

Comment: @JohnSUN Woah so funny that i can not stop laughing. Listen i already fix couple issues when `LibreOffice` don't show part of document. And there the same case, more likely that i made mistake in code that dudes who have been making `LibreOffice` for 20 year long.

Comment: I was not joking, I made a guess. Glad it turned out to be fun. Nevertheless, when I save a document from the Word as a Text OpenDocument (ODT), and after that the same Word cannot open it, I also diligently convince myself that I made a mistake (and there are no conspiracies against an open office). Anyway, I wish you the best of luck! I can't help - I use the mechanisms of LibreOffice and its API for the same task. But if you can find the reason of this trouble - be kind, let us know

Comment: @JohnSUN Well i spent a day to find a solution, and no results. Guess that time to move to other api. Sadge.