# How can I make PhpWord to cross out text for LibreOffice?

Tags: php, libreoffice, phpword

I use PhpWord for documents generation. And it's all right but one thing: if I try to cross out text with "strikethrough" style. It works properly for Microsoft Word and other text editors but LibreOffice. LibreOffice does not strike text at all, except if I open a document with Microsoft Word and resave it, then LibreOffice start to format text as expected.

Adding styles like this:

```
$document = new PhpWord();
$section = $document->addSection();
$text = $section->addText("something to cross out");
$text->setFontStyle(["strikethrough" => true]);
```

Saving document like this:

```
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($document, "Word2007");
$writer->save("some/directory/document.docx");
```

I tried to use PhpWord versions 0.18.1 and 0.17.0 and had no difference.
Please, help me. What should I do?

Comment: The description of your difficulties is very similar to the difficulties described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67195910/14094617). You will probably not be able to find a solution, try changing the tool (IMHO)

Comment: Also seems to be posted on https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1693, but they don't seem to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: @NigelRen Those two who did not confirm the error did not indicate which of the programs they checked - if they used Word, they could not see the wrong behavior. @Ivan Try this trick (this is from the realm of inexplicable shamanism). First add a single space `addText(" ")`, then apply strikethrough `setFontStyle(["strikethrough" => true])` and immediately add the correct `addText("something to cross out")`. (I vaguely remember that a similar trick worked for someone in a similar situation)

Comment: @NigelRen, thanks. I saw it before, but I didn't take it seriously. I downgraded version to 0.15.0 and it works all right. I will use it if I will not find other solution

Comment: I've left a comment on the issue with the results of my own debugging. Perhaps that will help to identify the issue.